# Problems with EmusicJ on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, music, proprietary

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 in my new machine and have a subscription to emusic (because I used it before in my Windows days because of the great selection of classical music). I have used it on my old machine (running older versions of Ubuntu) with some success but am having difficulties doing so now.

I am trying to use EmusicJ but do not/cannot remember how to do so. I have downloaded the program and unzipped it and ran the following command in a terminal:

```
./emusic
```

If I remember correctly, once I go to the emusic site and download my music, the EmucisJ program should open and begin downloading the music through that program but this time it is not and I have already wiped my old box in order to give it to a friend.

Any help is appreciated as I would like to continue with Emusic, but if I cannot get this resolved I will likely have to cancel my subscription and find a better alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you using 32-bit or 64-bit? I believe you downloaded it from [here](http://www.kallisti.net.nz/EMusicJ/Download), if not, from where did you download the zip file?

Comment: The 64-bit version and yes Jobin I did get it from the link you have in your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly do you go to download music so that emusicj should start downloading?

Comment: Just the emusic website.